# DialogInterface with a long click listener?

Tags: android, click, onclicklistener

I would like to have a dialog that listens for short **and** long clicks (when the user holds their finger on an item and react to it by playing a preview of an audio file, without closing the the DialogInterface (sort of providing some convenience to the user).

After checking the API on the [DialogInterface class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html), I see that it only offers an OnClickListener. Is it possible the make the DialogInterface object listen for **both**?

Here's the code:

```
public class SetMetronomeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Pick a tempo");
    builder.setItems(R.array.tempoArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // this code works fine since it's from the Android Developer site :)
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + which, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
        }

       // this is my 'dream method', doesn't work of course...
       public void onLongClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + which, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [setView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29) on your `AlertDialog.Builder` and then add the listeners you want to your custom view.

Comment: I suppose I need to subclass ListView, right? Or are there any other options?

Comment: Why a listview ? You could use any view, probably one of your own, maybe a simple button, it all dependends on the view you want.

Comment: Allright. Actually the way it looks now is almost perfect, except that it doesn't listen for long clicks.